# Shiny app doesn't print output

Tags: r, web-applications, shiny

I'm working on this mortgage calculator app and I can't get it to display the output values.  It should be generating the monthly payment, and then the flag for if the mortgage is affordable or not based on income.

I can't seem to figure out why it's not generating the output.  The formulas all work when run as a separate R script.

Here's my server.R file:

```
library(shiny)
shinyServer(
  function(input, output){
    output$pitiPayment <- renderText({piti(input$tax, input$insurance, input$principal, input$annualInterest, input$loanTerm, input$downPayment) })
    output$Affordable <- renderText({affordability(input$tax, input$insurance, input$principal, input$annualInterest, input$loanTerm, input$downPayment, input$income)})

  }
)

monPayment <- function(principal, annualInterest, loanTerm, downPayment) { 
  monthlyInterest <- annualInterest/(12 * 100)
  termMonths <- 12 * loanTerm
  monthlyPayment <- round((principal-downPayment)*monthlyInterest/(1-(1+monthlyInterest)^(-termMonths)),2)
  return(monthlyPayment)
}

piti <- function(tax, insurance, principal, annualInterest, loanTerm, downPayment) {
  monthlyPayment <- monPayment(principal, annualInterest, loanTerm, downPayment)
  taxPayment <- (principal*(tax/100))/12
  insurancePayment <- ((insurance/100)*principal)/12
  monthly <- round(monthlyPayment + taxPayment + insurancePayment,2)
  return (monthly)
}

affordability <- function(tax, insurance, principal, annualInterest, loanTerm, downPayment, income) {
  pitiPayment <- piti(tax, insurance, principal, annualInterest, loanTerm, downPayment)
  pctofIncome <- pitiPayment/income
  if (pctofIncome > 0.3){
    affordable <- "This loan is not affordable."
  } else {
    affordable <- "This loan is affordable."
  }
  return(affordable)
}
```

Here's my ui.R file:

```
library(shiny)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("Mortgage Calculator"),
  sidebarPanel(
    h4('Property'),
    textInput('text', 'Address', value='123 Elm'),
    numericInput('principal', 'Price ($)', 250000),
    numericInput('downPayment', 'Down Payment ($)', 50000),
    h5('Mortgage Info'),
    numericInput('annualInterest', 'Mortgage Rate (excl % sign)', 6),
    numericInput('Tax', 'Mil rate ($ per $100 valuation)', 3.5),
    numericInput('loanTerm', 'Loan Term in years', 30),
    h5('Mortgage Info'),
    numericInput('insurance', 'Insurance cost, as a % of value (excl % sign)', 2),
    h5('Income'),
    numericInput('Income', 'Monthly Income', 6000)
  ),
  mainPanel(
    h4('Total Housing Cost Per Month'),
    textOutput("pitiPayment"),
    h4('Affordable?'),
    textOutput("Affordable"),

    br(),
    h4('Instructions'),
    helpText("This application calculates the 'PITI payment' for a given property and mortgage, the total monthly cost including mortgage, insurance and taxes."),
    code("monPayment"),
    helpText("Enter the property's cost, the amount of down payment, the tax rate and the insurance cost to calculate the monthly cost of ownership."),
    code("affordability"),
    helpText("Enter your monthly income to determine if the mortgage is affordable;  affordability is defined as 30% of monthly income.")
  )
))
```

Comment: You have case typos : `input$Tax` and `input$Income`

Comment: Thanks - don't know how I missed it.  Works now.